# How to call forkJoin in switchOperator?

Tags: typescript, rxjs, rxjs5

I have tried to call forkJoin in `switchMap`:

```
this.route.params.pipe(
  pluck('cadnum'),
  tap((cadnum) => {
    this.r1.repositoryModel.findallversionbycadnum.model.cadnum = cadnum;
    this.r2.repositoryModel.findallversionbycadnum.model.cadnum = cadnum;
    this.r3.repositoryModel.findallversionbycadnum.model.cadnum = cadnum;
  }),
  switchMap(() => forkJoin(
    egrn.parcels.versions.load(),
    egrn.premisses.versions.load(),
    egrn.rights.versions.load()).pipe(
      tap(([res1, res2, res3]) => {
        egrn.parcels.versions.set(res1);
        egrn.premisses.versions.set(res2);
        egrn.rights.versions.set(res3);
      }),
      catchError((error) => of(error)),
    ),
  ),
)).subscribe((response) => {
  console.log(response);
});
```

But it does not work, how to call `forkJoin` inside `switchMap`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To forkJoin emit the results all `egrn.parcels.versions.load(), egrn.premisses.versions.load(), egrn.rights.versions.load()` have to be complete.

You can try to switch `forkJoin` to `combineLatest` or finish the streams after the first emission with `take(1)`, example: `egrn.parcels.versions.load().pipe(take(1))`

Comment: Could you explain more with examsples?

Comment: It does not work because I should subscribe on `forkJoin`. SwitchMap have to do that, but not